# How to append to values?

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there is a way to append to values that are arrays.. for example

```
<input type="text" id="someID" name="text[]"/>
```

How do you append to that in javascript?
Normally, I would just get the contents of value then append to it but it's an array here so I'm not sure how to do it

Code for appending for a non-array

```
var newvalue = 50;
var value = document.getElementById('someID').value;
document.getElementById('someID').value = value+newvalue;
```

Now, what I need is for PHP to get that array with the value 50 in it

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try it, the value of an input can't be an array, adding the brackets just makes some serverside software, like PHP, parse it as an array.

Comment: @adeneo I know and that is what I am intending to do, I just want to add to the array another value which will be processed like a value inside an array by a language like PHP

Comment: im sorry but i didnt get the question? could you clarify please?

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo Question edited

Comment: If you're trying to add to the array that PHP creates for you, you have to add a hidden input with the same name.

Comment: sorry. still cant understand. maybe someone else can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `hidden` input with desired `value` and same `name` to the form.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" name="numbers-form">
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]" value="30" />
    <input type="text" name="numbers[]" value="40" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var formArray = (function() {
    var form = document.forms['numbers-form'],
        inputName = 'numbers[]';
    return {
        getNumbers: function() {
            // NodeList to Array
            var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(form[inputName]);
            return nodesArray.map(function(input) {
                return input.value;
            });
        },
        addNumber: function(number) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = inputName;
            input.value = number;
            form.appendChild(input);
        },
        printNumbers: function() {
            console.log(this.getNumbers());
        }
    };
})();

formArray.printNumbers();
formArray.addNumber(50);
formArray.printNumbers();
formArray.addNumber(60);
formArray.printNumbers();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/6TaLp/)